# R plot isoclines for a given value (z), where x*y=z

Tags: r, ggplot2, solver

I am attempting to plot a line that includes all of the products of `x` and `y` that equal a given value (`z`).

Right now I can make a matrix of all the `x` and `y` pairings and then hopefully get enough entries within `group_id` to be able to plot the line. This is not elegant and is more approximate than I would like for setting a value of `z` to plot.

Is there a smarter way to do this than what I have listed below? I'd rather just provide vectors of `x` and `y` and be able to plot a line where `x*y = z`, where I provide the value of `z`. Is this more of a "solver" type question?

With the example I provided, I need to alter `A` (x) and `B` (y) to ensure that I will get a value for `AB` (z) that I am seeking. This approaches requires a fair bit of fiddling with `seq` for each set of values.

Instead, I would prefer a solution where I provide the target value of `AB` and the minimum and maximum values of both `A` and `B`. Then, from these values, a curve could be drawn after some computation. Approximately 30 points seem to be able to display the shape of the curve for my needs.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create a data.frame with each combination of values of A and B
df <- expand.grid(A = seq(0, 1, 0.001), B = seq(0, 100, .1))

# possible products of A and B
df$AB <- with(df, A*B)

# make a for each unique AB
df$group_id <- df %>% group_indices(AB)

# how many entries in the group, need enough to plot
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(group_id) %>% 
  mutate(nID = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

df2 <- df1 %>% filter(AB > 0)

# an example to plot more than one line
#df3 <- df2 %>% filter(nID > 40)

# an example to plot just one line
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  filter(AB == 8.316)

# plot isocline
df3 %>% #group_by(group_id) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = A, y = B, color = factor(AB))) + geom_line()

###
```

Comment: I am not guaranteed the `z` of interest will be included using the above or below, without a lot pre-checking when using expand grid. I'd like to be able to select any `z` (provided it would be contained within the range of `x*y`

Comment: it might be me, but I don’t understand this … within the range - as in _any_ value in that range , or only those values that x*y actually take ? and what is it that you are looking for?

Comment: let me phrase the question as I understand it now: you are given a value z. and you want to know if the values of your new vector x*y contain enough z in order to plot a line? how many points do you define as a cut-off for “enough”? (you can draw a line through two points already)

Comment: also, are x and y always going to be sorted? (e.g. only increasing)? and will they have only unique values? although I don’t know how right now, this information might be of relevance for an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment, not sure what your actual question is. I think you're just looking for a function. You also don't need all that grouping steps. Below just a suggestion.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- expand.grid(A = seq(0, 1, 0.001), B = seq(0, 100, .1))

draw_z <- function(df, z){
df %>%
  mutate(AB = A*B) %>% 
  filter(AB > 0, AB == z) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = A, y = B)) + 
  geom_line()
}

draw_z(df, 8.316)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>